# What data type does find method return?

Tags: vba, methods, find

I am trying to search 3 columns contained in the range specified below. I have spent a long time looking online and I have found similar questions but when I apply it to mine I am not getting the correct answer. So far (from another questions answer) I have:

```
Dim result As Range 
Set result = range("DailyTable[[AmtNumberOut]:[AMTOutstanding]]").find(What:="#N/A Requesting Data...", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
    xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
    xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If result Is Nothing Then

ElseIf IsEmpty(result.Offset(0, 2)) Then
    MsgBox ("Please wait for information to finish downloading. Import cancelled.")
    Exit Sub
Else
    MsgBox ("Please wait for information to finish downloading. Import cancelled.")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

I understand that find returns nothing if no value is found which can cause issues with data types but I have tried defining result as Range, Object, Variant, String and all give mismatch error. I also read somewhere that it can return Boolean outputs (which did not work either). I have spent a long time stuck on a simple problem and I would be very grateful for any answers!

Thanks.

Comment: Remove your variable declaration `Dim result As Range` and `Option Explicit` if exists in your module. This way the variable type will be assigned automatically. Run your code step by step and see in your **Locals** window the type of variable assigned.

Comment: Microsoft Developers states that the Range.Find method returns a Range object that represents the first cell where that information is found.

Comment: @DavidG. People usually tell askers to *add* `Option Explicit`, not to remove it! The type will be `Variant/Range`; `Variant` because it's going to be implicitly declared on-the-fly thanks to the omission of `Option Explicit` (**VERY BAD IDEA**), and `/Range` because at the end of the day the function *is* returning a `Range` object. Actually it could also be `Variant/Error` given a worksheet error cell and a missing `Set` keyword in front of `result =`.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I ask to do it just for testing purposes. **Not to remove it definitely.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your find you have

```
After:=ActiveCell,
```

This throws a mismatch error if your active cell is not in the table you reference, "DailyTable".

Also, your logic will have the message box appear if the offset is empty or not.  So if Result is nothing, then nothing, but if the offset is empty or not, you get the message.  As long as that's what you want, then why are you checking the offset to be empty?

Comment: I ran this code because I haven't seen the table reference in the range before (I just don't use tables very much) and wanted to test it and see how it worked.  It was a good learning exercise.

Comment: Oh, you're going to LOVE tables! They're the single best Excel feature since ....forever!

Answer (score 1):

`Range.Find` returns a `Range` object reference, initialized or not, period. If `Range.Find` found anything, you get a `Range` object reference, otherwise you get `Nothing`, which is an uninitialized object reference that will make your code throw run-time error 91 "object reference not set" if you try to make member calls against it.

> I have tried defining result as Range, Object, Variant, String and all give mismatch error.

You want a `Range`. `Object` would work, however it would make all member calls made against it late-bound, i.e. resolved at run-time - you'd get no IntelliSense or auto-completion, and VBA would happily compile a typo **regardless of whether** `Option Explicit` **is specified**.

`Variant` would work as well, but again you'd lose IntelliSense, and you'd be wrapping the object reference into a `Variant/Object`, which incurs overhead you don't need.

`String` is dangerous. First, for it to even have any chance to work you need to drop the `Set` keyword. And then this is what you're *really* doing, with both the implicit default member access and implicit type conversion made explicit:

```
Dim result As String
result = CStr(Range(...).Find(...).Value)
```

The implicit default member call `.Value` is illegal against `Nothing` in the first place, and then there's no guarantee that the `CStr` string conversion will succeed: if the cell contains an error value (e.g. `#N/A`), then this is where you're getting a *type mismatch* run-time error, because an `Error` value can't be implicitly (or explicitly) converted to a `String` (or anything, actually).

If you're getting a *type mismatch* with `result As Range`, then you're doing something with the returned `Range` object's `Value` (implicitly or explicitly) and that value is an `Error` - you can't compare an error value against any type. You need to wrap whatever it is you're doing with it, with `If IsError(result) Then` - but it looks like none of the code you posted would cause a *type mismatch* error with `Dim result As Range`, assuming `.Offset(0,2)` isn't an error value either.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I thought I understood the basic principles of object orientated programming... At one point I was trying Boolean data type and that did work when the result was True- but failed when nothing.